# Case where Linux can be made to Crash or Hang in CPL3 (User Mode) without Root Acces?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, crash

While the Current Privilege Level CPL is 3 (which means that the system was in user mode) if we encounter a Crash that normally means that the hardware is faulty as System should not crash in User Mode. However there are some cases in which system can be made to crash or hang without

**Operating System Considering:** `Ubuntu`

**Question:**

What Other (`2-3`) possible scenarios(`Briefly`) can cause such crash without hardware failure. Please also give some Code references for the Understanding if you can.

Comment: Your example isn't even a good one; Linux will _struggle_ if you cause a fork bomb, but it won't crash; Being too slow is not the same as having crashed. Memory leaks - same deal, except on top, Linux has the _OOM Killer_ to kill abusively leaking processes. Real ways to crash the system while at CPL3 are things like the F00F C7C8 instruction (an example of an HCF instruction) on Pentiums, the now-disabled TSX instructions on Haswell, or certain sequences of stack pointer manipulations on certain AMD steppings that made the stack pointer incorrectly update.

Comment: @iwillnotexist and how the system can be hanged such that I have to reboot it.

Comment: Bugs that crash an operating system are considered security issues and are a matter of closely guarded secrets that generally don't leak out until they are fixed. There are people who pay good money for this kind of information as long as it's secret, so until stackoverflow reputation is actually convertible into real money I doubt anyone will give you a useful answer.

Comment: you can get a handy tool for finding situations like that [here](http://crashme.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: `YOU CAN'T`.
Alain Knaff, who is the writer of linux kernel says; And i Quote

> This is Linux, not Windows, and Linux doesn't have any bugs which
> would allow you to do this. There is a reason, after all, why more and more >people are ditching
> Windows, and using Linux. Ofcourse, you could always try manipulating
> the hardware (blocking the CPU fan to make the CPU overheat, jiggling
> the memory SIMMs, etc.), but I guess that wouldn't really count...

Moreover u can crash your kernel from user mode in the  earlier kerenel versions 2.0 etc . From user mode if u send the ping packet more than 653476 but conditional to earlier version of Linux kernel..current kernels have been resolved this Bug.

Also that A null pointer dereference flaw was discovered in the Linux kernel's SCTP implementation when ASCONF is used. A remote attacker could exploit this flaw to cause a denial of service (system crash) via a malformed INIT chunk one more, A race condition with MMIO and PIO transactions in the KVM (Kernel Virtual
Machine) subsystem of the Linux kernel was discovered. A guest OS user
could exploit this flaw to cause a denial of service (guest OS crash) via a
specially crafted application

Comment: and agreed to Art as the person commented above , such bugs are available on lunched only ,,they are not available as u are asking. these are the kind of security issues in respect of operating systems